# How to verify if a resource is of type .c, .h, .s in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a `TableViewer` which is filled with data based on the selected resource. For files I'm checking the received item like this:

```
if( item instanceof IFile ) {
  something;
}
```

I saw that .c, .h, .s files aren't of type `IFile` but of type `ICElement`. When I checked this I saw that also the folders are of this type.

Because I need informations only from the selected files the following question comes:

What is the main class from which all the resources are derived? I want to be sure that my viewer will be filled if a file of any type is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects you get from the current selection often aren't instances of the underlying resource but can be 'adapted' to the resource using:

```
IAdapterManager adapter = Platform.getAdapterManager();

IResource resource = (IResource)adapter.getAdapter(selectedObject, IResource.class);

if (resource instanceof IFile)
 {
   ....
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the main class from which all the resources are derived ?

I would say `IResource` (IFile, IFolder and IProject are subinterfaces)

And if you want to handle files accordingly to their extension, just parse the extension :)

[IResource doc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html)

Comment: You should always use the content type manager to get the type of files.